# Matlab error using nlinfit, ill-conditioned Jacobian

Tags: matlab, non-linear-regression

I am using the `nlinfit` function in Matlab to plot a line of best fit to sets of data that I have. The function I am using is `f = @(a, b) 1 - exp(-(x/a)^b)`. For most of the data sets this works fine, but for some the graphs are way off, and I'm getting the warning:

> Warning:
>   The Jacobian at the solution is ill-conditioned, and some model parameters may not be estimated well (they are not identifiable). Use caution in making predictions.

I found that usually we roughly have `a=5, b=5`, but that for the incorrect fits `nlinfit` gives `a=0, b=-0.02` or `a=4.6, b=174`. I have included the graphs and data points below.
[image: good fit] [image: a=0] [image: b=174]

```
x    y3    y2    y1
0.8  0     0.08  0
1.8  0     0     0.17
2.8  0     0     0
3.3  0.08  0     0
3.7  0     0     0.17
4.0  0     0     0.33
4.6  0.75  0.67  0.67
4.9  0.92  0.42  0.75
5.3  0.83  0.5   0.83
5.8  0.92  0.83  1
6.8  1     0.92  1
7.8  1     1     1
```

What is going wrong?!

Comment: Can you post some of the data sets that you're trying to fit?

Comment: You want the exact values of what is shown on the graph??

Comment: Yes.  Not the fit, just the data.

Comment: @jeff added as requested.

Comment: Oops, I just realized that I don't have the stats toolbox, so I can't use nlinfit.  Hopefully someone else can help you.